# Can i install Ubuntu 10.4 enterprise cloud in virtualbox

Tags: server, virtualbox, cloud, uec

I would like install Ubuntu enterprise cloud in virtual box and need to test it, will UEC 
can be installed successfully in Virtual box & where can i get Tutorial for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No you can't. UEC requires hardware virtualization, as far as I know.

You CAN use [OpenNebula](http://opennebula.org/about%3aabout) with software virtualization.

You're going to take a drastic performance hit running virtualization inside of virtualization though.

I haven't tested it, but if you want to try UEC on the cheap [this](http://ubuntu-smoser.blogspot.com/2010/05/easily-test-or-demo-ubuntu-enterprise.html) may work.